# Basic CSS Positioning center

Tags: html, css

JSFiddle link -[Code](https://jsfiddle.net/aLxecdk6/)

I have wasted an hour on this stupid problem. I have made projects and it worked. I deleted that code in rage.

I wanted to center an image but there was a heading above the image. So, i wrapped them in a div and gave them a id[x].

What i tried `#x` - `margin:0 auto` `width:50%; margin:auto;` `width:50%; margin: 0 auto;` `width:50%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` and changing positions to relative.

What worked **[not wrapped in a div]**  -

```
    img {   
        display:block;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    h1 {
        color:blue;
        text-align:center;
    }
```

But this code had a problem as the image is clickable, the whole width of where the image was became clickable, i don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have a `block` element inside an `inline` element. The anchor that the image would be wrapped in is an `inline` element. When you turn the child  into a block element it will make the anchor take the entire width of the line, because you don't have a width setting on the anchor.

To fix this issue, `display:block;` should be `display:inline-block;`

Use `text-align: center` to center the image.

```css
#test {
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
h1 {
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <h1>Hi, I am guy!</h1>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/200/200">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: That's weird that you have to wrap them in a div and do so much alignment and <h1> text align is unnecessary.

Comment: That's just the easiest way to center a bunch of elements. Put them inside a wrapper and set `text-align: center`. The h1 text-align was a remnant. I've removed it.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your problem you want to both center the header and image that are wrapped in a div. You do not want the entire area of the div clickable just the image. Below is a fiddle.

If the above is correct it seems you just need to add the a tag around the img tag and not the div itself.

```
<div>
 <h1>Header</h1>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=200%C3%97200&w=200&h=200" /></a>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gward90/7s45osxa/

UPDATE:

display: block will take up the width of the parent element everytime, as others have said use inline-block.

Only apply size to the img tag, and apply display to the a tag. The wrapper class with text-align: center is actually taking care of centering the img as well.

Here is the updated fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/gward90/7s45osxa/3/

Here is also your fiddle updated with my suggestions
https://jsfiddle.net/gward90/aLxecdk6/5/

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what i did but your code has the same problem, the whole width becomes a link.

Comment: Please explain further you only want part of the image clickable ?

Comment: I want only the image to be clickable